# Minimal Polynomials Annihilating an Abelian Torsion-Free Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, polynomials

Let $A$ be an abelian torsion-free group. Let $\theta \in\operatorname{Aut}A$. Assume that $\theta$ has a finite period in $\operatorname{Aut} A$, say $n$. Obviously $\theta^n-1$ annihilates $A$ (i.e. $A^{\theta^n-1}=\{0\}$, where $\theta^n-1$ is now the obvious endomorphism of $A$). 
Thus, there is a polynomial of minimal degree with integral coefficients annihilating $A$, say $g(\theta)$. Can we assume that it is also a monic polynomial?

I would like to say that, for instance, $g(\theta)\mid \theta^n-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've studied injective envelopes or tensor products this can be handled in a smooth way. Let $E(A) = A \otimes \mathbb{Q}$ be the injective envelope of $A$. Then $\phi: A \to A$ can be considered $\phi:A \to E(A)$ and since $A \leq E(A)$ and $E(A)$ is injective, there is an extension $\tilde \phi : E(A) \to E(A)$. Since $E(A)$ is torsion-free the extension turns out to be unique and still an automorphism. Since $E(A)$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$, you can use all your old minimal polynomial ideas. This works over commutative domains (and Ore domains), but be careful when you use Gauss's lemma if the domain is not a UFD. :-)

Comment: (If $A$ was not torsion-free, then there can be multiple extensions, and I don't think automorphisms are necessarily preserved, at least over arbitrary rings. However, it continues to be neat to look at endomorphisms of modules in terms of endomorphisms of their injective envelopes. This is why you sometimes see endomorphisms of abelian p-groups written over the p-adics integers.)

Comment: Let's see if I got this right.
Let $E(A)$ be the tensor product $A \otimes \mathbb{Q}$. We have $A\leq E(A)$ by $a\in A \mapsto a\otimes 1\in A \otimes \mathbb{Q} $. The extension $E(A)\rightarrow E(A)$ is now the following one: $a\otimes q \mapsto \phi(a)\otimes q$. Thus, if we have $g(\phi)=m\phi^k+...$ we can extend it to $E(A)$ in the following way: $(a\otimes q)^{g(\phi)}=a^{\phi^k} \otimes mq+... $. How can we go back to $A$? (Probably I do understand nothing =D)

Comment: Everything you said sounds right. $g(\phi)$ acts as 0 on $E(A)$ if and only if it acts as 0 on $A$. Notice that $a \otimes \frac{p}{q} + b \otimes \frac{p'}{q} = (ap + bp') \otimes \frac{1}{q}$ and $q \cdot g(\phi)(a \otimes \frac{1}{q}) = g(\phi)(a)$. Torsion-free lets you just divide by $q$.

Comment: I miss something...
Taking $g(\phi)=m_k\phi^k+...+m_0$ we want to show that there is a monic polynomial with integral coefficients of the same degree that annihilates $A$. This can be done in $E(A)$ with rational coefficients from the extension of $g(\phi)$ dividing by $m_k$, say $\psi(\tilde \phi)=\tilde \phi^k+...+m_0/m_k$. So $m_k*\psi(\tilde \phi)(a\otimes 1)=m_k*(a^{\phi^k}\otimes 1+...+a\otimes m_0/m_k)=0$ and then $\psi(\tilde \phi)(a\otimes 1)=0$. 
This is a reformulation of what you said, but I still do not figure out how to obtain the integral coefficients. :(

Comment: The integral coefficients come from Gauss's lemma according to my possibly flawed memory. I think this is just the (monic versions of the) factors of $x^n-1$ have integer coefficients. I guess a general $\phi$ wouldn't have to have a monic integral minimal polynomial. For instance, if $A=\mathbb{Q}$ and $\phi(x) = x/2$ then $g=2x-1$ or $g=x-1/2$.

Comment: First, I'm not so practice of this, so sorry for my pedantry. In the above notation, we have $\psi(\tilde \phi)/\tilde \phi^n-1$. Considering the polynomials simple as polynomials in $\mathbb Q[x]$, it follows that $x^n-1=\psi(x)*t(x)$. By Gauss's lemma there is some non-zero rational number $\lambda$ such that $\lambda\psi$ and $\lambda^{-1} t$ both have integral coefficients. Then $\lambda$ and $\lambda^{-1}$ must be integer and so $=\pm1$. It yields that $\psi(\tilde \phi)$ has integral coefficients, monic and we can go back to $\psi(\phi)$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.